# Any way to delay process execution?

Tags: java, groovy

I'm writing a wrapper script using Groovy (but the question is really a Java one) and would like to know if it's possible to create a Process without letting it run first. The problem is that the Process starts running and generating output on stdout and stderr. I would like to forward those to their appropriate destinations and at the same time create a merged stream for processing within the script. The problem I'm running into, however, is that the Process generates output too quickly and the output on the first two lines is a bit garbled. I would like to setup the streams before the process starts running. Any way to do that?

Comment: can you post a snippet of what you've tried so far?

Comment: Would Thread.sleep() not work for you?

Comment: You can have a look at Thread.join() too.

Comment: Java/groovy is not the best choice for something that depends as much on the OS as process control. In the unix world you would `fork` the current process, set up its I/O, and `exec` the new program. In Windows this model does not exist; instead you can create a new process in a stopped state.

Answer (score 0):

This consumes the output and error streams into two separate StringWriters, but I don't see anything "garbled"

```
new StringWriter().with { out ->
  new StringWriter().with { err ->
    'ls /tmp'.execute().with { proc ->
      consumeProcessOutput( out, err )
      waitFor()
    }
    println "OUT: $out"
    println "ERR: $err"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for trying but in practice the Process is still started and running before the consumeProcessOutput() call gets a chance to do anything about it. It's not long but it's also variable - suppose a GC happened in between for example.

Comment: But the process should be writing into the streams, that's why if you don't consume them things can start to hang... Do you have an example we can run that exhibits the problem you're seeing?